# In what order should imports be done in React?

Tags: css, reactjs, import

I know I have to import React first in component files:

```
import React from 'react';
// other imports...
```

I've also heard that imports with styles and images should be imported last:

```
// other imports...
import * as Styles from './styles.css';
import exampleIcon from '../icons/example-icon.svg';
```

Why should I import icons, images and styles last? What about the order of other imports (components, utilities, constants, etc.) - is there a standard/documentation for imports order?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any standard doc for that, but there's easy way which makes you not to care about that anymore..
If you use Visual Code for developing, just install `vsc-organize-imports` extension for Visual Code.. It will help you to organize imports automatically by default options..
Good luck..

Answer (score 0):

I think We don't have any standard for that, my standard is like this, and I have seen a lot of people import code in this order.

React and React Hooks

packages

components

styles

Answer (score 0):

The imports will be the following order :
•   react, react-dom, react-router,
•   and (the ui library)
•   package/third-party imports, such as lodash.
•   project alias imports
•   relative imports

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin for Prettier:

[Prettier plugin sort imports](https://github.com/trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports)

It helps you to import declarations by provided Regular Expression order.

First, you need to install Prettier, then install the above plugin.
After that you need to create a file and name it exactly ".prettierrc" and import the plugin properties into the file.
You just need to follow the plugin Github description.